# Average of column value over all values before

Tags: python, pandas

my dataframe looks like this:

```
Time            Amount
2020-01-01      63
2020-01-02      200
2020-01-03      342
2020-01-04      91
2020-01-05      500
2020-01-06      200
```

What I would like to do is compute the average for every row including the amounts of all the rows above.

output should look like this:

```
Time            Amount    Average
2020-01-01      63        NaN
2020-01-02      200       131.5
2020-01-03      342       201.67
2020-01-04      91        174
2020-01-05      500       239.2
2020-01-06      200       232.67
```

I thought about using .rolling().mean() but I always want to include all datapoints and not exclude the first one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.expanding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html) with `mean` and then if necessary set `NaN` to first value:

```
df['new'] = df['Amount'].expanding().mean()
df.loc[0, 'new'] = np.nan
print (df)
         Time  Amount         new
0  2020-01-01      63         NaN
1  2020-01-02     200  131.500000
2  2020-01-03     342  201.666667
3  2020-01-04      91  174.000000
4  2020-01-05     500  239.200000
5  2020-01-06     200  232.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just `cummean`. You may implement `cummean` with simple calculation as

```
df.Amount.cumsum() / np.arange(1, df.shape[0]+1)

Out[766]:
0     63.000000
1    131.500000
2    201.666667
3    174.000000
4    239.200000
5    232.666667
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

To make the first cell as `NaN`, there is no other simpler way than direct assign as in @jezrael.

---

**Timing**: a raw testing show it ~3x faster than `expanding.mean`

```
In [774]: df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

In [775]: %timeit df['Amount'].expanding().mean()
970 µs ± 1.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [776]: %timeit df.Amount.cumsum() / np.arange(1, df.shape[0]+1)
330 µs ± 1.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```